# golang goroutine practice, function or channel?

Tags: go, websocket, concurrency, channel, goroutine

constantly receive Json data from websocket and process them in goroutine, no idea is this writing pattern is encourage or not

```
    ws.onmessage {     //infinite receive message from websocket
        go func() {   //work find using this goroutine
            defer processJson(message)
        }()
        
        go processJson(message) //error and program will terminated
     }
    
    func processJson(msg string) {
        //code for  process json 
    
        insertDatabase(processedMsg)
    }
    
    func insertDatabase(processedMsg string) {
        //code insert to database
    }
```

Below(the first goroutine) work just fine, but sometime(a week) indicates there is a data race in the code and terminate the program.

```
    go func() {  
        defer processJson(message)
    }()
```

the second goroutine,   often encounter error after few minutes running, the error often is "fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution".

```
    go processJson(message)
```

from my understanding both goroutine do the samething, why is that the first can run well and second cannot. i have try using channel, but not much difference compare to the first goroutine.

```
    msgChan := make(chan string, 1000)
    go processJson(msgChan)

    for {   //receive json from websocket, send to channel
        msgChan <- message
    }

    func JsonProcessor(msg chan string) {
       for {   //get data from channel, process in goroutine function
           msgModified := <-msg
           insertDatabase(msgModified)
       }
    }
```

is there any encourage way to acheive the goal without data race, suggestions are welcome.
Appreciate and Thanks.

Comment: `go processJson(message)`   do the samething  as fllow code   `go func(msg string) { defer processJson(msg)}(message)`, maybe it is the bug

Answer (score 0):

try to use `sync.Mutex` avoid data racing

```
mutux := sync.Mutex{}
ws.onmessage {
  processJson(message)
}
func processJson(msg string) {
  mutux.Lock()
  // .........
  mutux.Unlock()
}
```

if the processing function can be divided without data racing, multithread version as follows :

```
msgChan1 := make(chan string, 1000)
msgChan2 := make(chan string, 1000)

go func() {
  for m := range msgChan1 {
    // ...
  }
}()
go func() {
  for m := range msgChan2 {
    // ...
  }
}()

ws.onmessage {
  msgChan1 <- message
  msgChan2 <- message
}
ws.onclose {
  close(msgChan1)
  close(msgChan2)
}
```